# rocket chip riscv rtl spike simulation

Tags: riscv, device-tree, spike, memory-mapped-io

I use mmio axi4 for data store, the rtl simulation in vcs is ok, but in spike, I got error like this:

```
(base) ubuntu@ubuntu:~/riscv/software$ spike math.elf
Access exception occurred while loading payload math.elf:
Memory address 0x60000000 is invalid
```

This is the device tree dumped by spike --dump-dts command:

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
  #address-cells = <2>;
  #size-cells = <2>;
  compatible = "ucbbar,spike-bare-dev";
  model = "ucbbar,spike-bare";
  chosen {
    stdout-path = &SERIAL0;
    bootargs = "console=ttyS0 earlycon";
  };
  cpus {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    timebase-frequency = <10000000>;
    CPU0: cpu@0 {
      device_type = "cpu";
      reg = <0>;
      status = "okay";
      compatible = "riscv";
      riscv,isa = "rv64imafdc";
      mmu-type = "riscv,sv57";
      riscv,pmpregions = <16>;
      riscv,pmpgranularity = <4>;
      clock-frequency = <1000000000>;
      CPU0_intc: interrupt-controller {
        #address-cells = <2>;
        #interrupt-cells = <1>;
        interrupt-controller;
        compatible = "riscv,cpu-intc";
      };
    };
  };
  memory@80000000 {
    device_type = "memory";
    reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x0 0x80000000>;
  };
  soc {
    #address-cells = <2>;
    #size-cells = <2>;
    compatible = "ucbbar,spike-bare-soc", "simple-bus";
    ranges;
    clint@2000000 {
      compatible = "riscv,clint0";
      interrupts-extended = <&CPU0_intc 3 &CPU0_intc 7 >;
      reg = <0x0 0x2000000 0x0 0xc0000>;
    };
    PLIC: plic@c000000 {
      compatible = "riscv,plic0";
      #address-cells = <2>;
      interrupts-extended = <&CPU0_intc 11 &CPU0_intc 9 >;
      reg = <0x0 0xc000000 0x0 0x1000000>;
      riscv,ndev = <0x1f>;
      riscv,max-priority = <0xf>;
      #interrupt-cells = <1>;
      interrupt-controller;
    };
    SERIAL0: ns16550@10000000 {
      compatible = "ns16550a";
      clock-frequency = <10000000>;
      interrupt-parent = <&PLIC>;
      interrupts = <1>;
      reg = <0x0 0x10000000 0x0 0x100>;
      reg-shift = <0x0>;
      reg-io-width = <0x1>;
    };
  };
  htif {
    compatible = "ucb,htif0";
  };
};
```

This is the device tree generated when compile verilog in rocket chip:

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    compatible = "freechips,rocketchip-unknown-dev";
    model = "freechips,rocketchip-unknown";
    L15: cpus {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        timebase-frequency = <1000000>;
        L4: cpu@0 {
            clock-frequency = <0>;
            compatible = "sifive,rocket0", "riscv";
            d-cache-block-size = <64>;
            d-cache-sets = <64>;
            d-cache-size = <16384>;
            d-tlb-sets = <1>;
            d-tlb-size = <32>;
            device_type = "cpu";
            hardware-exec-breakpoint-count = <1>;
            i-cache-block-size = <64>;
            i-cache-sets = <64>;
            i-cache-size = <16384>;
            i-tlb-sets = <1>;
            i-tlb-size = <32>;
            mmu-type = "riscv,sv39";
            next-level-cache = <&L10>;
            reg = <0x0>;
            riscv,isa = "rv64imafdcZicsr_Zifencei_Zihpm_Xrocket";
            riscv,pmpgranularity = <4>;
            riscv,pmpregions = <8>;
            status = "okay";
            timebase-frequency = <1000000>;
            tlb-split;
            L2: interrupt-controller {
                #interrupt-cells = <1>;
                compatible = "riscv,cpu-intc";
                interrupt-controller;
            };
        };
    };
    L10: memory@80000000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x80000000 0x10000000>;
    };
    L14: soc {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        compatible = "freechips,rocketchip-unknown-soc", "simple-bus";
        ranges;
        L6: clint@2000000 {
            compatible = "riscv,clint0";
            interrupts-extended = <&L2 3 &L2 7>;
            reg = <0x2000000 0x10000>;
            reg-names = "control";
        };
        L7: debug-controller@0 {
            compatible = "sifive,debug-013", "riscv,debug-013";
            debug-attach = "dmi";
            interrupts-extended = <&L2 65535>;
            reg = <0x0 0x1000>;
            reg-names = "control";
        };
        L1: error-device@3000 {
            compatible = "sifive,error0";
            reg = <0x3000 0x1000>;
        };
        L9: external-interrupts {
            interrupt-parent = <&L5>;
            interrupts = <1 2>;
        };
        L5: interrupt-controller@c000000 {
            #interrupt-cells = <1>;
            compatible = "riscv,plic0";
            interrupt-controller;
            interrupts-extended = <&L2 11 &L2 9>;
            reg = <0xc000000 0x4000000>;
            reg-names = "control";
            riscv,max-priority = <3>;
            riscv,ndev = <2>;
        };
        L11: mmio-port-axi4@60000000 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            compatible = "simple-bus";
            ranges = <0x60000000 0x60000000 0x20000000>;
        };
        L12: rom@10000 {
            compatible = "sifive,rom0";
            reg = <0x10000 0x10000>;
            reg-names = "mem";
        };
        L0: subsystem_pbus_clock {
            #clock-cells = <0>;
            clock-frequency = <100000000>;
            clock-output-names = "subsystem_pbus_clock";
            compatible = "fixed-clock";
        };
    };
};
```

Generated Address Map

```
       0 -     1000 ARWX  debug-controller@0
    3000 -     4000 ARWX  error-device@3000
   10000 -    20000  R X  rom@10000
 2000000 -  2010000 ARW   clint@2000000
 c000000 - 10000000 ARW   interrupt-controller@c000000
60000000 - 80000000  RWX  mmio-port-axi4@60000000
80000000 - 90000000  RWXC memory@80000000
```

I also tried command like this: spike --dts=./device.dtb math.elf, but it's not working.